# Error - Error in createDataPartition(data_YT$rating_scale, p = m, list = FALSE) : y must have at least 2 data points

Tags: r

I am trying to run this piece of code :

```
for(i in 1:9) {
    set.seed(1000)
      m <- i/10
      print(m*10)
      trData = createDataPartition(data_YT$rating_scale, p = m ,list = FALSE)
      train_Data <- data_YT[trData,]
      test_Data <- data_YT[-trData,]
      
      ctree_model <- ctree(rating ~ ., data = train_Data)
      predDT <- predict(ctree_model,test_Data)
      tab <- table(predDT,test_Data$rating_scale)
      correctclass <- sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)*100
      print(correctclass)
      incorrect <- (1- sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)) * 100
      print(incorrect)
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Error - Error in createDataPartition(data_YT$rating_scale, p = m, list
> = FALSE) :    y must have at least 2 data points

Comment: Unrelated to the error message, but calling `set.seed` inside a loop (or a function) is pretty much *always* an error. `set.seed` works best if it’s called only once inside an application (there are specific, rare exceptions but these aren’t relevant here).

Comment: Please provide something similar to your `data_YT` dataset in order to reproduce.